# A question about commutative $R$-algebras.

Tags: ring-theory

Aluffi describes a commutative $R$-algebra as a ring homomorphism $\alpha:R\to S$ where $S$ is commutative.

Going by this definition, how is $R[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ a commutative $R$-algebra? What is $S$ here?

Answer (score 1):

You call a ring $S$ an $R$-algebra, if you have such a ring homomorphism $R \to S$ (more strictly speaking, the definition that I know is: an $R$-algebra is a commutative ring $S$ together with a ring homomorphism $R\to S$). Often such a homomorphism happens to be canonical or obvious, hence one omits stating the homomorphism.

In your case one says $S=R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is an $R$-algebra, by the natural embedding $R \to R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The $R$-algebra is $R \to R[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$, $r \mapsto r$ (viewed as a constant polynomial).

Comment: Yes but an $R$-algebra is defined as a homomorphism between two rings. I don't understand how $R[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ is a homomorphism here. Going by your mapping, it seems to be a mapping.

Comment: $R[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is a ring. Strictly speaking it is not an $R$-algebra. The homomorphism of rings $R \to R[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is an $R$-algebra. Every $R$-algebra $R \to S$ has an underlying ring, namely $S$. Usually one abuses notation and just writes $S$ for the $R$-algebra (although it is just a ring). So one does if $S$ is a polynomial ring over $R$.

Comment: So just confirming, an $R$-algebra is any homomorphism from $R$ to another commutative ring?

Comment: Yes, this is a commutative $R$-algebra. (forgot to add this above.)